# How does hornetq persist messages?

Tags: jboss, hornetq

We are in the process of planning our server machine switch.  While we are doing the switch, we need to be able to continue to receive traffic and save the JMS messages that are generated.

Is it possible to move the persisted message queue from one JBoss 7.1.1/HornetQ to another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use export journal / export data... or you can use bridges to transfer data.

You should find some relevant information at the documentation on hornetq.org

Answer (score 2):

HornetQ uses a set of binary journal files to store the messages in the queues.